# Prevent execution of functions within <Collapse> until expanded, when using ReactJS with Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI within my ReactJS app to create a table that, when clicked, expands to show more detailed info (a new row just beneath the clicked row). As example, here is a minimal toy example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-collapse-table-forked-t6thz

The code relevant to the problem is:

```
<Collapse
  in={open}
  timeout="auto"
  TransitionProps={{
    mountOnEnter: true,
    unmountOnExit: true,
  }}
  mountOnEnter
  unmountOnExit
>
  <div>
    {/* actual function calls here; produces JSX output */}
    {console.log("This should not execute before expanding!")}
    Hello
  </div>
</Collapse>;
```

Do note that the `console.log()` statement is just a simple replacement for my actualy functionality, which involves some API calls that are made when a row is clicked, and the corresponding info is displayed. So instead of `console.log()` I would actually call some other function.

I find that the `console.log()` statement executed on initial page render itself, even though `in=false` initially. How can I prevent this? Such that the function calls take place only when the Collapse is expanded. I initially thought this would be automatically handled by using `mountOnEnter` and `unmountOnExit`, but that does not seem to be the case. Any help would be appreciated, that could fix this problem in the sample example above.

I am working on an existing open source project, and therefore do not have the flexibility to restructure the existing codebase a lot. I would ideally have loved to implement this differently, but don't have that option. So posting here to know what options I might have given the above scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, huge thanks to Matt for his [detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68400202/7383605). I worked through his example, and expanded on it to work for me as required. The main takeaway for me was: "Move the Collapse children to its own React component."

The solution posted by Matt above, I felt, didn't completely solve the problem for me. E.g. if I add a `console.log()` statement to the `render()` of the new child component (`<Example>`), I still see it being executed before it is mounted.

[image: Edit Material Collapse Table (fetching data) (forked)]

Adding `mountOnEnter` and `unmountOnExit` solved this problem:

[image: Edit Material Collapse Table (fetching data) (forked)]

But as Matt mentioned, the number of times the children were getting rendered was still a problem. So I slightly changed some bits (also simplified the code a bit):

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Essentially, I do this now:

My child component is:

```js
function Example(props) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        fontSize: 100,
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "white",
        backgroundColor: "#43A047"
      }}
    >
      {props.flag && console.log("This should not execute before expanding!")}
      {props.value}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and I call it from the parent component as:

```js
<TableRow>
  <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
    <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
      <Example value={row.name} flag={open} />
    </Collapse>
  </TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

Note that the parameter `flag` is essential to avoid the function execution during closing of the `<Collapse>`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

The children are rendered on initial load because they're defined within the `Row` component.

#### Solution

Move the `Collapse` children to its own React component. This won't render the children until the `Collapse` is opened. However, it'll re-render the child component when `Collapse` is closed. So depending on how you're making the API call and how other state interacts with this component, you *may* want to pass `open` to this component and use it as an `useEffect` dependency.

For example:

```
const Example = ({ open }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {...};

    if(open) fetchData();
  }, [open]);

  return (...);
}
```

#### Demo

[image: Edit Material Collapse Table (fetching data)]

#### Code

A separate React component:

```
const Example = ({ todoId }) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    error: "",
    data: {},
    isLoading: true
  });
  const { data, error, isLoading } = state;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(
          `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${todoId}`
        );
        if (res.status !== 200) throw String("Unable to locate todo item");
        const data = await res.json();

        setState({ error: "", data, isLoading: false });
      } catch (error) {
        setState({ error: error.toString(), data: {}, isLoading: false });
      }
    };

    fetchData();
    /* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "white",
        backgroundColor: "#43A047"
      }}
    >
      {error ? (
        <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</p>
      ) : isLoading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <>
          <div>
            <strong>Id</strong>: {data.id}
          </div>
          <div>
            <strong>Title</strong>: {data.title}
          </div>
          <div>
            <strong>Completed</strong>: {data.completed.toString()}
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The `Example` component being used as children to `Collapse` (also see supported [Collapse props](https://material-ui.com/api/collapse/#props)):

```
<Collapse
  in={open}
  timeout="auto"
  // mountOnEnter <=== not a supported prop
  // unmountOnExit <=== not a supported prop
>
  <Example todoId={todoId + 1} />
</Collapse>
```

#### Other Thoughts

If the API data is static and/or doesn't change too often, I'd recommend using `data` as a dependency to `useEffect` (similar to the `open` example above). This will limit the need to constantly query the API for the same data every time the same row is expanded/collapsed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt, I am still playing around with your solution to understand how I can get it to work for me. But I had a query in the meantime....

I am a bit confused about whether `mountOnEnter` and `unmountOnExit` are valid props for `<Collapse>` or not.

Comment: E.g. https://material-ui.com/components/transitions/ states that: "The Transition component's mountOnEnter property prevents the child component from being mounted until in is true. This prevents the relatively positioned component from scrolling into view from it's off-screen position. Similarly the unmountOnExit property removes the component from the DOM after it has been transition off screen." and shows an example of using this with `<Slide>`. But if you check the docs page for `<Slide>` it doesn't show up in the props: https://material-ui.com/api/slide/#props

Comment: But in both cases, i.e. docs for `<Collapse>` and `<Slide>` states that: "Any other props supplied will be provided to the root element (Transition)."... and `mountOnEnter` and `unmountOnExit` are, I believe, valid props for `Transition`. Or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: Looks I missed the typescript types explaining that `Collapse` inherits `Transition` props. So, I was wrong, `mountOnEnter` and `unmountOnExit` are supported! That said, this may lead to performance issues since it's adding/removing the children from the DOM. For example, if you have many open rows and/or complex data being consumed by Collapse children, then constantly re-rendering by adding/removing the children from the DOM may lead to some micro-stuttering. You can reduce the children re-renders by wrapping the `Example` component with `React.memo`.

Comment: On another note, be careful about using a `flag`. Because it's conditionally rendering (presumably) JSX when `Collapse` is open, it will be removed from the DOM when `Collapse` is closed and cause [a wonky animation](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2uxql)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out about the wonky animation! I will keep that in mind, and try to work out a more complete solution. Also, thanks for the tip about using React.Memo..... wasn't aware of it.